# Installation Heroku CLI via Git Bash

Tags: bash, heroku, heroku-cli

I try to install the heroku CLI for Windows 10 by using the Windows installer.

However, I always get the error message:

**bash: heroku: command not found.**

I can find the program in the windows app section. However, when I search for the program in my windows command prompt, I cannot find the path of "heroku".

I am not sure how git bash, heroku and the whole underlying mechanism is working. Therefore, I could not figure out a solution.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git, but it is very basic bash: bash *finds* programs by searching a "path". Windows (CMD, Powershell, etc) does the same sort of thing but uses a different name for the variable that holds the path. With bash, the variable that holds the path is spelled `PATH` (all uppercase: bash is case-sensitive) and the elements *in* the path are separated by colons: `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` for instance. If you need to put `C:\Program Files\whatever` into `$PATH`, you must spell this with forward slashes. Also, spaces matter to bash, so you must quote spaces.

Comment: This all adds up to, e.g., `PATH='/bin:/usr/bin:/C/Program Files/whatever'` (use single or double quotes here; there's some difference; read up on shells and bash to find out what).